# My onion skin doesn't work

Tags: animation, 2d

When I switch to the next frame the previous frame disappear, I tried to convert a General 3d preset into a 2d Animation to understand better how it works but I think that something's missing.

Also Idk how to change the color of the world in solid.

http://sendanywhe.re/RIKOF9WM here's my file

Comment: Hi. Please add some images to explain your post. While links to files can be good, we ideally want questions to be answerable without having to download anything, which means clear, well explained (and illustrated) question content.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)